# How is it supposed to work that "#define stdin stdin" in /usr/include/stdio.h?

Tags: c, stdio

In /usr/include/stdio.h

```
/* C89/C99 say they're macros.  Make them happy.  */
#define stdin stdin
#define stdout stdout
#define stderr stderr
```

How is this supposed to work?

Comment: Read the comment above.

Comment: @iharob The comment explains *why* they're defined; it doesn't explain *how* the macros work.

Comment: @jamesdlin Despite 6 upvotes to the comment, you are completely right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key point is that once a macro has been expanded, it is not replaced again in the replacement text.  That means that when the preprocessor comes across `stderr`
in:

```
fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file [...]\n", argv[0]);
```

it replaces the `stderr` token with `stderr`, and then rescans the replacement text, but `stderr` is no longer eligible for expansion, so the text remains `stderr`.

Answer (score 4):

A macro is not re-expanded again after its own expansion, so you do not end up with a circular (and infinite) macro expansion.

From section 6.10.3.4/2 of the ISO C99 standard:

> If the name of the macro being replaced is found during this scan of the replacement list (not including the rest of the source file’s preprocessing tokens), it is not replaced. Furthermore, if any nested replacements encounter the name of the macro being replaced, it is not replaced. These nonreplaced macro name preprocessing tokens are no longer available for further replacement even if they are later (re)examined in contexts in which
>   that macro name preprocessing token would otherwise have been replaced.

Answer (score 2):

The macro is replaced textually with the value it is defined to, so each one is replaced exactly by the same value. Just defining them as macros to make them "*macros*", but they are replaced by themselves so it's like doing nothing and just being standard compliant.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. It does replace itself with itself once.

However, in C11 6.10.3.4p2 there is a rule that says the macro name is not replaced again.

Answer (score 0):

Although the others explained the mechanism of the preprocessor, the actual reason for it is that `stdin` et al. are global variables, file pointers to be exact. See [GlibC-code](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/libio/stdio.c) for the details.

Your example defines a macro named `stdin` (and `stderr` and `stdout`) to be replaced with the global variable `stdin` (and `stderr` and `stdout`), so strictly spoken, both `stdin`s (and `stderr`s and `stdout`s) in the macro are not the same.